# HazelCast NoClassDef error

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using HazelCast in of my applications, it was running well. I had to undeploy and redeploy the application due to system maintenance. Now, when I try to bringup the application, I keep getting this error in my hazelcast. Can someone help me with this? I made no changes to my application. It was simply a Windows Upgrade that needed the server to reboot.

```
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev] is STARTING
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_dev] is STARTED
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientClusterService
INFO:

Members [1] {
        Member [172.31.21.118]:8444
}

Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:59834
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] 8444 accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:59834
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationRequest
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Received auth from Connection [/127.0.0.1:59834 -> null] live=true, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, successfully authenticated
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Accepting socket connection from /172.31.21.118:60986
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] 8444 accepted socket connection from /172.31.21.118:60986
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:49 AM com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationRequest
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Received auth from Connection [/172.31.21.118:60986 -> null] live=true, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, successfully authenticated
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:50 AM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Connection [Address[172.31.21.118]:60986] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:50 AM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngine
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Destroying ClientEndpoint{conn=Connection [/172.31.21.118:60986 -> Address[172.31.21.118]:60986] live=false, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, uuid='9795307d-0af4-4f18-aaf2-67b15239ccb0', firstConnection=false, authenticated=true}
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:50 AM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Connection [Address[127.0.0.1]:59834] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:50 AM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngine
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Destroying ClientEndpoint{conn=Connection [/127.0.0.1:59834 -> Address[127.0.0.1]:59834] live=false, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, uuid='9795307d-0af4-4f18-aaf2-67b15239ccb0', firstConnection=true, authenticated=true}
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:50 AM com.hazelcast.nio.ReadHandler
WARNING: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[172.31.21.118]:60986, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
Aug 10, 2017 4:30:50 AM com.hazelcast.nio.ReadHandler
WARNING: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-2 Closing socket to endpoint Address[127.0.0.1]:59834, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
Exception in thread "hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-42" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/cluster/MulticastJoiner$1
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:93)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:46)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:36)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.ManagedExecutorService$Worker.run(ManagedExecutorService.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastJoiner$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 8 more
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:22 AM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:59888
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:22 AM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] 8444 accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:59888
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:22 AM com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationRequest
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Received auth from Connection [/127.0.0.1:59888 -> null] live=true, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, successfully authenticated
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:23 AM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Accepting socket connection from /172.31.21.118:32808
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:23 AM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] 8444 accepted socket connection from /172.31.21.118:32808
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:23 AM com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationRequest
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Received auth from Connection [/172.31.21.118:32808 -> null] live=true, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, successfully authenticated
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:23 AM com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngine
SEVERE: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/map/client/MapClearRequest
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/map/client/MapClearRequest
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:290)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:219)
        at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.run(ClientEngineImpl.java:346)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.ManagedExecutorService$Worker.run(ManagedExecutorService.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/map/client/MapClearRequest
        at com.hazelcast.map.MapPortableHook$1$30.createNew(MapPortableHook.java:256)
        at com.hazelcast.map.MapPortableHook$1$30.createNew(MapPortableHook.java:254)
        at com.hazelcast.map.MapPortableHook$1.create(MapPortableHook.java:307)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.read(PortableSerializer.java:77)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.read(PortableSerializer.java:29)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:213)
        ... 6 more

Exception in thread "hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/client/ClientEndpoint$3
        at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEndpoint.getClientType(ClientEndpoint.java:104)
        at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngineImpl.sendResponse(ClientEngineImpl.java:135)
        at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.run(ClientEngineImpl.java:392)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.ManagedExecutorService$Worker.run(ManagedExecutorService.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59)
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:33 AM com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Accepting socket connection from /172.31.21.118:32810
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:33 AM com.hazelcast.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] 8444 accepted socket connection from /172.31.21.118:32810
Aug 10, 2017 4:32:33 AM com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationRequest
INFO: [172.31.21.118]:8444 [dev] Received auth from Connection [/172.31.21.118:32810 -> null] live=true, client=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT, successfully authenticated
Exception in thread "hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-7" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/cluster/MulticastJoiner$1
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:93)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:46)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:36)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.ManagedExecutorService$Worker.run(ManagedExecutorService.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might have JARs of multiple versions of Hazelcast in your classpath. Since the classpath is often random order, you might get a class of JAR A and a class of JAR B and so on. Please see if you have a clean classpath. Only one Hazelcast version should be around.

Comment: multiple versions were running. managed to get it cleaned up. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is related to Java classloading...

It has nothing to do with Hazelcast itself but with your environment.
You are running an JEE server and have most certainly multiple copies of Hazelcast in your effective classpath.
which interfere with each other (probably where each is loaded by a different classloader).

OR

This could also happen if you restarted or hot-deployed your application.